# Laravel's Eloquent method getKey() returns the first number of the UUID

Tags: php, laravel, primary-key, uuid, cartalyst-sentinel

I have a `User` and a `Role` model extending [Catalyst's Sentinel](https://github.com/cartalyst/sentinel) package.

Everything works fine if I use the default incrementing primary key. When I change it to use UUIDs it acts weird. Everything works fine except for a little detail.

Here's the [code snippet](https://github.com/cartalyst/sentinel/blob/dc0f3ecbbcb2d3f9fbd5f1b9d990524f30ef79e1/src/Users/EloquentUser.php#L202) to check whether the `User` belongs to a `Role` or not:

```
public function inRole($role)
{
    if ($role instanceof RoleInterface) {
        $roleId = $role->getRoleId();
    }
    foreach ($this->roles as $instance) {
        if ($role instanceof RoleInterface) {
            if ($instance->getRoleId() === $roleId) {
                return true;
            }
        } else {
            if ($instance->getRoleId() == $role || $instance->getRoleSlug() == $role) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

What that code does is: if I pass an instance of `Role` it loops through all the user's roles and check whether any of them match the provided `$role`'s id.

Here's the `$user->roles` (`$this->roles`) relationship:

```
public function roles()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(static::$rolesModel, 'role_users', 'user_id', 'role_id')->withTimestamps();
}
```

The `$role->getRoleId()` correctly returns the UUID: `"8fbc99e2-3cbb-4e98-b0e3-4c88027d787f"`

But the `$instance->getRoleId()` returns `8`, or whatever the first numeric character of the UUID is. If the first character is a letter then it returns `0`.

I have confirmed that `$instance` is indeed an instance of `RoleInterface` so I think it should behave exactly the same as `$role`.

I have also added `public $incrementing = false` to both models.

I have made several checkpoints across all the vendor functions that are called and I can't figure out why this is happening.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

I have opened a new issue on their GitHub repository so here's the link to keep the answers in sync: github.com/cartalyst/sentinel/issues/289 (sorry, I can't post more than 2 links)

Comment: Are you by chance casting this value to int in the `$casts` array?

Comment: @user3158900 I don't think so. Where do I find that array? But even if I did, wouldn't both calls have to return the same thing?

Comment: Does setting the protected $keyType = 'string'; property in your models works?

Comment: @scrubmx It doesn't  work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a bug in the package and it has been fixed: https://github.com/cartalyst/sentinel/commit/239fa9ec88ce8fb955f5c0d85311d55a2f76e314

Answer (score 0):

This bug has been fixed, but if you have very old laravel version, it helped me to add this code to the model

```
public function getKeyName() {
    if (isset($this->id)) {
        return 'id_'; // any non-existed column  
    } else {
        return 'id'; // real id column name 
    }
}

public function getKey() {
    return $this->id;
}
```